# Media print cortando linha da tabela

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo o CSS para impressão de uma tabela, basicamente eu removo todos os elementos da página e deixo só a tabela quando a janela da impressão é aberta.
Faço isso utilizando:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/impressao.css" media="print" />`

O problema é que quando a busca retorna mais de uma página, algumas linhas ficam nas duas(topo da letras em uma página e abase na outra):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual melhor forma para eu resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não tenho o código para testar fica difícil te dar certeza absoluta como vai ficar o resultado. Mas na teoria, segundo a documentação, vc pode controlar essa fragmentação.

> Cada ponto de quebra possível (em outras palavras, cada limite de elemento) é afetado por três propriedades: o `break-after: valor` do elemento anterior, o `break-before: valor` do próximo elemento e o `break-inside: valor` do elemento contido.

Não vou me alongar em cada uma delas, mas vc pode consultar aqui a documentação da Mozilla, que é mais amigável que a **[documentação da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/)**

- **break-inside** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside
- **break-before** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before
- **break-after** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after

No seu caso acredito que vc não quer cortar a tabela no meio, então use a propriedade `break-inside:avoid`

```
@media print {
  table {
    break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

Ou se quiser que uma table sempre comece em uma nova página coloque

```
@media print {
  table {
    break-before: page;
  }
}
```

Minha dica é que se não der certo tente com `after` e `before` tb, pois como te disse não tenho um ambiente para testar isso. E recomendo para vc a leitura dessa artigo da Smashing Magazine, que deve te interessar e fala um pouco sobre a **Fragmentação** https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/#css-fragmentation

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou ler as documentações e ver o que consigo fazer!